Choosing random sample of requests from stream
Suppose that I would like to divert 10% of requests coming into an API to some other service. The request needs to be sent to the service at the time the request is processed. The requests should be chosen at random. How do I design / implement something like this?
From what I see online the options are:

Assign each request a 10% chance of being diverted. i.e roll a random number generator if the number is <= 0.1, divert. Supposedly this works because the expected value of each request being diverted is 0.1, so for n requests 10% of requests would be diverted.

Reservoir Sampling - Apparently this algorithm is meant for streams, but the implementations I see online all wait for N requests to be completed before actually processing the reservoir. In other words, if I have 100 requests, I need to process all 100 requests first before I can process the 10 requests that need to be sent to the other service.


So is Option 1 correct? I'm imagining the math like a 10 sided die where one of the sides is "1" and the rest are "0", and each time a request comes in you roll the die. There's a 10% chance that the die will land on 1, and if you roll the die 100 times you expect 1 to show up 10 times. So I imagine this would work.

You haven't provided a clear definition of "correct" so we can't tell you whether it is correct, but in most practical applications I would expect that Option 1 is preferable, because it is stateless, can be implemented efficiently, and performs satisfactorily (the fraction that are diverted in practice will be very close to 10%).
